# Can't print normal page size

Tags: printing

Ubuntu 12.04. When I print it cuts off about an inch at the bottom. Is there someway to change the print page size?

Comment: In what application you are trying to print? Normally there is a page setup tab, that allows you to select "paper size".

Answer (score 2):

1. Search for and launch *Printers* in Dash.
2. Right click on your printer, and select *Properties*.
3. Select *Job Options*.
4. Check the *Scale to fit* option.
5. Click *OK*.